# How can I control an objects location on a curve with a given axis? Or have the objects movement being relevant to a specific axis?

Tags: bezier-curves

I want to have an object follow along the curve. I'd like for the object to move at a constant velocity in the X direction regardless of the Y-displacement on the curve.

I tried using the clamp-to constraint and then parented the object to an empty. But it doesn't follow the empty 1:1 and will shoot off down the curve.

Is there someway to achieve this?

Comment: This may be fundamentally impossible to guarantee, since a curve is not necessarily expressed as x(y) function and can have multiple points with the same X coordinate

Comment: That is a great point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with animation nodes.

The nodes setup:

[image]

the "func" Subprogram defines the function you are using. The function should describe the curve in a mathematical expression, so that you can calculate your y/z value depending on your x value.
For demonstration purpose i just took the timeframe as x value.

And of course i just took some "phantasie" function:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Beautiful thank you. I had a hunch there was an Animation nodes work around but didn't have the time to play around yet. It looks like this method jumps from point to point is that correct?

Comment: It calculates every point, so the bigger you make the divide value, the smoother it will run

Comment: You are welcome